# Passing Selection Model Table Row To Server in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular7

I'm trying to send the selected data in my table row that I am selecting via a checkbox to the server but having questions about how it should be sent via a service. I have the basic skeleton but need help with getting the items to a delete REST API call. Using C# .Net Core JSON call as the server endpoint for this service call.

**view.component.ts**

```
    @Component({
  templateUrl: 'view.component.html'
})
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  // User Fields
  currentUser: User;
  users: User[] = [];
  currentUserSubscription: Subscription;

  loading : boolean;
  // Action Fields
  viewData: any;
  viewName: string;
  refNumber: number;
  currentActionSubscription: Subscription;
  displayedColumns: string[] = [];
  dataSource: any = new MatTableDataSource([]);
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [10, 20, 50];

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  selection = new SelectionModel<TableRow>(true, []);

  defaultSort: MatSortable = {
    id: 'defColumnName',
    start: 'asc',
    disableClear: true
  };

  defaultPaginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(
    private iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private actionService: ActionService
  ) {
    this.loading = false;
    this.iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      'thumbs-up',
      this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
        'assets/img/examples/thumbup-icon.svg'
      )
    );
  }

  loadAction(action: any) {

    this.loading = true;
    // If there is already data loaded into the View, cache it in the service.
    if (this.viewData) {
      this.cacheAction();
    }

    if (this.sort) {
      // If there is sorting cached, load it into the View.
      if (action.sortable) {
        // If the action was cached, we should hit this block.
        this.sort.sort(action.sortable);
      } else {
        // Else apply the defaultSort.
        this.sort.sort(this.defaultSort);
      }
    }

    if (this.paginator) {
      // If we've stored a pageIndex and/or pageSize, retrieve accordingly.
      if (action.pageIndex) {
        this.paginator.pageIndex = action.pageIndex;
      } else { // Apply default pageIndex.
        this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
      }

      if (action.pageSize) {
        this.paginator.pageSize = action.pageSize;
      } else { // Apply default pageSize.
        this.paginator.pageSize = 10;
      }
    }

    // Apply the sort & paginator to the View data.
    setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.sort = this.sort, 4000);
    setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator, 4000);

    // Load the new action's data into the View:
    this.viewData = action.action;
    this.viewName = action.action.ActionName;
    this.refNumber = action.refNumber;

    // TODO: add uniquifiers/ids and use these as the sort for table

    const displayedColumns = this.viewData.Columns.map((c: { Name: any; }) => c.Name);
    displayedColumns[2] = 'Folder1';
    this.displayedColumns = ['select'].concat(displayedColumns);
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    const fetchedData = this.viewData.DataRows.map((r: { slice: (arg0: number, arg1: number) => { forEach: (arg0: (d: any, i: string | number) => any) => void; }; }) => {
      const row = {};
      r.slice(0, 9).forEach((d: any, i: string | number) => (row[this.displayedColumns[i]] = d));
      return row;
    });

    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(fetchedData);
    this.loading = false;
  }

  // Stores the current Action, sort, and paginator in an ActionState object to be held in the action service's stateMap.
  cacheAction() {
    let actionState = new ActionState(this.viewData);

    // Determine the sort direction to store.
    let cachedStart: SortDirection;
    if (this.sort.direction == "desc") {
      cachedStart = 'desc';
    } else {
      cachedStart = 'asc';
    }

    // Create a Sortable so that we can re-apply this sort.
    actionState.sortable = {
      id: this.sort.active,
      start: cachedStart,
      disableClear: this.sort.disableClear
    };

    // Store the current pageIndex and pageSize.
    actionState.pageIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex;
    actionState.pageSize = this.paginator.pageSize;

    // Store the refNumber in the actionState for later retrieval.
    actionState.refNumber = this.refNumber;
    this.actionService.cacheAction(actionState);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Subscribes to the action service's currentAction, populating this component with View data.
    this.actionService.currentAction.subscribe(action => this.loadAction(action));
  }

    /** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
    isAllSelected() {
      const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
      const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
      return numSelected === numRows;
    }

    /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
    masterToggle() {
      this.isAllSelected()
        ? this.selection.clear()
        : this.dataSource.data.forEach((row: TableRow) => this.selection.select(row));
    }

    // Delete row functionality

    deleteRow() {
      console.log(this.selection);
      this.selection.selected.forEach(item => {
        const index: number = this.dataSource.data.findIndex((d: TableRow) => d === item);
        console.log(this.dataSource.data.findIndex((d: TableRow) => d === item));
        this.dataSource.data.splice(index, 1);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.dataSource.data);
      });
      this.selection = new SelectionModel<TableRow>(true, []);
      this.actionService.deleteRow(this.selection).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log('Success!');
      });
    }


  ngOnDestroy() {

  }
}
```

**view.service.ts**

```
  deleteRow(selection: any): Observable<{}> {
console.log('testing service');
return this.http.delete<any>(`http://localhost:15217/actions/deleteRow`);
```

}

Comment: Single delete or multiple?

Comment: single or mutiple delete based on the object in the collection

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things that your code as it currently stands needs to do:

1. Pass the ids of the selected rows back to the server in some way (generally via the url in a DELETE request)
2. Subscribe to the observable to materialise it. Currently the http request won't run, because it's an observable without any subscribers. At the very least the call to the service in the component should look a little like this:

```
this.actionService.deleteRow(this.selection).subscribe((response) => {
  console.log('Success!');
});
```

Edit:

With number 1, it depends on what your server method looks like. If it accepts an array of numeric ids, then **view.service.ts** would look something like:

```
deleteRow(selection: SelectionModel<TableRow>): Observable<{}> {
  console.log('testing service');
  // create an array of query params using the property that you use to identify a table row
  const queryParams = selection.selected.map(row => `id=${row.id}`);
  // add the query params to the url
  const url = `http://localhost:15217/actions/deleteRow?${queryParams.join('&')}`;
  return this.http.delete<any>(url);
}
```

I'm guessing here at how you pass information about table rows to your server. If you're still struggling with this, you will need to provide a bit of information about the DELETE endpoint.

Edit 2:

Now we know a bit more about what the objects look like...

```
deleteRow(selection: SelectionModel<TableRow>): Observable<{}> {
  console.log('testing service');
  // create an array of query params using the property that you use to identify a table row
  const queryParams = [...selection._selection].map(row => `id=${row.id}`);
  // add the query params to the url
  const url = `http://localhost:15217/actions/deleteRow?${queryParams.join('&')}`;
  return this.http.delete<any>(url);
}
```

Comment: right right... but how would I do 1 and maybe extend 2? That's pretty much I need help with

Comment: I've updated my answer to illustrate what number 1 might look like, depending on your server configuration. Number 2 doesn't need much extending to get it to work, although you will probably want to put some feedback to the user in there. How you do that is entirely up to you, and outside the scope of this question.

Comment: hmmm this helps. I feel like I'm close to the answer but I'm also getting a error in the console with ```selection.map is not a function```  which I'm assuming is based on query params or id of a selected row.

Comment: I don't know what the structure of selection is, so I guessed at it being an array. map() is an array function. Can you let me know what the data structure of selection is, then I will be able to help more.

Comment: There isn't any need for selection to be given the `any` type here, as I presume you know what the data type is.

Comment: just updated the component in the original post, it should give a better idea

Comment: I still don't know what the objects look like, but my guess is that you need to call `selection.selected.map(x => x.id)` - replacing "id" with your actual property.

Comment: I've updated my service example with a type on selection, and using the selected property to get the ids.

Comment: hmm thank you. this could probably give you a better idea of the object. I took a image capture of the selection model once clicked on a row. https://imgur.com/a/rGUX5sE

Comment: check it out I added an image

Comment: So which bit of the SelectionModel object do you need to send to the server? Is it what's inside _selection?

Comment: _selection is a set, which is why the .map() function doesn't exist on it. A shorthand for treating a set as an array is to do `[...mySet]`. So you could do `[selection._selection].map(..)`, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: yeah pretty much I have to send every object of the value in _selection to the server. Would [selection._selection].map(..) work, but what goes inside the (..)?

Comment: those would be the selected row that needs to be deleted once send to the server/database

Comment: and would this be in the service?

Comment: I've added a revised version to the end of my answer. This is all about understanding the fundamentals of what you're trying to achieve. You have some data in some kind of object, which you need to translate into a series of strings that are then converted into query params for an http request. Some of my detail might not be right, due to a lack of information, but hopefully you understand a bit more about the process now.